# Handling "Skip" in random forest and rpart

Tags: missing-data

I have a dataset that contains 30 variables out of which I need to combine 10 variables into 1 variable (interparental conflict). Each of these 10 variables contains about 68% missing data. Out of that, about 50% is "skip" since interparental conflict does not apply to single parents. I want to use this variable (interparental conflict) as a predictor variable for my outcome variable (child GPA) in rpart and randomforest. How do I handle "skip" in this case? I cannot impute it since the question is not applicable to single parents.

Comment: You could code it as another level, which would represent NA (or skip).

Comment: How will rpart or random forest handle it? Is there a way it can handle missingness?

Comment: Some implementations do handle missing values by using surrogate splits. But that was not my point, I suggested to replace the missing values (missing because of "skip") with another code, say "skip", and let the model figure out the associations.